# Pass selector value to a user defined variable not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I have the following situation:

When I try to pass a dynamic value to a css class it works, but when I use the same code for a variable defined by me it doesn't work anymore.

What am I missing here? Thanks

```
//Working, passes the value.
 $('#myVal').val($('[data-id="sel4'+ id_art +'"]').text());

//Not Working, no value shown.
 var myValue='';
 $(myValue).val($('[data-id="sel4'+ id_art +'"]').text());
```

Comment: You need to prefix `#` for Id selector and `.` for class selector. What is the value of `myValue` variable?

Comment: Why your variable is empty??? It should be var myValue='#myVal';

Comment: Sorry. I mean  id not css class* . The values are 1, 2 or 3 (radio buttons). The myValue variable is supposed to be used later in a Bootstrap Modal to show the checked radio button: $('input[name=RadioB][value="' + myValue + '"]').prop('checked',true);

Answer (score 0):

In `myValue` you should assign a DOM element you can't set it as blank or anything else. you can do like this

```
var myValue= $('#myVal');
```

Then

```
myValue.val($('[data-id="sel4'+ id_art +'"]').text());
```

it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Your defined variable is empty. It should be defined like `var myValue='#myVal';`

Please check below working demo snippet.

```js
//Not Working, no value shown.
 var myValue='#myVal';
 $(myValue).val('Test It');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myVal">
```